# if let nil in swift 2.0 is not working as expected

Tags: if-statement, core-data, nsdate, swift2, xcode7

"if let nil" check is not working in Swift 2.0, but was working fine in Swift 1.2.

In the below code, "fetchNumbersFromCoreDataDB" function returns nil. In getDatabaseDate function, I have a condition "if let date = dbDate". This condition ideally should fail and go to else block. But in Swift 2.0, it is going inside the if block. In Swift 1.2, same code is going to else block. I am confused here. What is the difference here?

```
 func getDatabaseDate() {
        let dbDate : NSDate? = ((self.fetchNumbersFromCoreDataDB(“123456”) as DBNumbers!).dbDate)
        if let date = dbDate {
           print(“\(date)”)
        }
        else {
            print(“No Date”)
        }
    }


 func fetchNumbersFromCoreDataDB(Number:String) -> DBNumbers? {
      var numArray = coreDataInterface.fetchAllObjectsFromEntity(info, withAttributeValues: [“No” : Number]) as! [DBNumbers]
      return numArray.count>0 ? numArray[0] : nil
 }
```

Note: "dbDate" is NSDate type in Coredata table

Comment: So it's printing the date, or crashing?

Answer (score 1):

The `let dbDate` line is very oddly constructed and would raise an exception if your `fetchNumbersFromCoreDataDB` were returning `nil`. Therefore your `fetchNumbersFromCoreDataDB` is not returning `nil`.

Your line:

```
let dbDate : NSDate? = ((self.fetchNumbersFromCoreDataDB(“123456”) as DBNumbers!).dbDate)
```

`as DBNumbers!` says to convert from `DBNumbers?` to `DBNumbers!`. So you've got an optional that is implicitly unwrapped.

Hence `.dbDate` says to unwrap the return result of `fetchNumbersFromCoreDataDB` and get the `dbDate` property from it. Had `fetchNumbersFromCoreDataDB` returned `nil`, the attempt to unwrap would raise an exception.

What you probably wanted was:

```
let dbDate = self.fetchNumbersFromCoreDataDB(“123456”)?.dbDate
```

Which says "if the optional returned by `fetchNumbersFromCoreDataDB` is not `nil` then get its `dbDate` property; otherwise get `nil`".

If you really need to convince yourself empirically, open a playground and try this:

```
class DBNumbers {
    var dbDate: NSDate?
}

func fetchNumbersFromCoreDataDB(Number:String) -> DBNumbers? {
    return nil
}

let dbDate : NSDate? = (fetchNumbersFromCoreDataDB("123456") as DBNumbers!).dbDate
```

You'll get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on the last line.